# Scheme: Why isn't my defined procedure being recognized?

Tags: scheme

```
(define rearrange 
  (λ ignore
    (define (proc1 x y) (+ x y))
    (foldr (λ (x y) (if (list? x) (append (rearrange x y) y) 
                        (if (procedure? x) 
                            (append y (list x)) (cons x y)))) empty '(a proc1 b))))
```

why isn't `x` being recognized as a procedure even though I defined it as such right before the call to foldr?

Comment: Why are you redefining `and` to be `or`? o.O

Comment: `'x` is not the same as `x`. `x` means Scheme will evaluate the symbol to get the value it represents, which could be any object including procedures and continuations, while `'x` always evaluate to the symbol `x` which might be the same symbol as a variable but it's not a variable in this context. Anything quoted is never anything but what you see. It will have no meaning for Scheme. Use `(list 'a and 'b)`. Now only `a` and `b` will be nothinc special but `and` will evaluate to a procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. In that list, `and` is not a procedure. It is a symbol.

This is due to how quoting works. The expression `'(a b c)` is effectively the same as `(list 'a 'b 'c)`, so `and` is literally evaluated as the symbol, `'and`.

Either explicitly use the `list` function to make your list, or use quasiquoting. Either of these expressions should produce what you want:

```
(list 'a and 'b)
`(a ,and b)
```